# I am using volley to post data to a device.I get connected to it by wifi.but in app: NoConnectionError! failed to connect to 192.168.4.1

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley, port

This is the code that I have written in Java in my app:
I can send data by a python code but in android studio : `failed to connect to 192.168.4.1`.

Can anyone give me a suggestion? I really need this to work.

```
private void sendDeviceDataPostRequest() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    String url = "http://192.168.4.1:3333";

    try {
        String URL = url;
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();

        //some data entry


        JsonObjectRequest jsonOblect = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //code
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    //code
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //some code

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                //some code
            }
        };
        queue.add(jsonOblect);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem using volley, but finally I solve it using TCP socket programming.
here is the code:
class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

```
private static Socket s;
private static PrintWriter printWriter;
String send_message = "";
private static String ip = "192.168.4.1";
public static final int port = 3333;
public void set_data(String msg){
    send_message = msg;
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        s = new Socket(ip, port);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        printWriter.write(send_message);
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
        s.close();



    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }






    return null;
}
```

}